# Run a Docker image as a container

Tags: docker, docker-image

After building a Docker image from a `dockerfile`, I see the image was built successfully, but what do I do with it? Shouldn't i be able to run it as a container?

Answer (score 1061, accepted):

The specific way to run it depends on whether you gave the image a tag/name or not.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 ID                  CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              12.04               8dbd9e392a96        4 months ago        131.5 MB (virtual 131.5 MB)
```

With a name (let's use *Ubuntu*):

```
$ docker run -i -t ubuntu:12.04 /bin/bash
```

Without a name, just using the ID:

```
$ docker run -i -t 8dbd9e392a96 /bin/bash
```

Please see *[Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)* for more information.

Comment: So the human-friendly names printed under 'NAME' in  `docker ps -a` is not useful here?

Comment: `docker ps` lists containers, not images. If you want to create an image from a container, you must `docker commit`. You can use the _NAME_ in the commit (e.g. `docker commit _NAME_ _imagename_`)

Comment: @Andy Why do we use /bin/bash at the end ? I am new also

Comment: @RaheelKhan Becaue your docker image needs something to run.  You could replace that with a program that you've installed. /bin/bash is just a handy shell that's already installed.

Comment: If you need to add an environment variable you can do docker run -i -t -e ROOT_PASSWORD=root ubuntu:12.04

Comment: @Andy, I've seen just `docker run -it <image>` and it runs the default shell. Works well with alpine, for example. And probably with other OS images where entry point has not been modified.

Comment: $ docker run  -d 8dbd9e392a96 /bin/bash

Answer (score 96):

Do the following steps:

1. `$ docker images`

   You will get a list of all local Docker images with the tags specified.
2. `$ docker run image_name:tag_name`

   If you didn't specify `tag_name` it will automatically run an image with the 'latest' tag.

   Instead of `image_name`, you can also specify an image ID (no tag_name).

Comment: I'm new to docker, it helps me, Thanks. Further we can check statuses for running images  *sudo docker ps -a*

Answer (score 54):

- To list the Docker images

  ```
  $ docker images
  ```
- If your application wants to run in with port 80, and you can expose a different port to bind locally, say 8080:

  ```
  $ docker run -d --restart=always -p 8080:80 image_name:version
  ```

Comment: This `--restart=always` option should be used always as a rule.

Answer (score 36):

You can see your available images using:

```
docker images
```

Then you can run in detached mode so your terminal is still usable. You have several options to run it using a repository name (with or without a tag) or image ID:

```
docker run -d repository
docker run -d repository:tag
docker run -d image_id
```

Then you can check your container is running using

```
docker ps
```

`docker ps` gives you a container ID. You can use it or just the 2/3 first characters to go into your container using:

```
docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash
```

And you can stop it using `docker stop container_id` and `docker rm container_id`.

You can also run your container with `--rm` arguments so if you stop your container it will automatically be removed.

Comment: The --rm (note: 2 dashes not single) option is gold!!!, my system is littered with stopped (dead) containers.

Answer (score 17):

Get the name or id of the image you would like to run, with this command:

```
docker images
```

The Docker run command is used in the following way:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Below I have included the dispatch, name, publish, volume and restart options before specifying the image name or id:

```
docker run -d --name  container-name -p localhost:80:80 -v $HOME/myContainer/configDir:/myImage/configDir --restart=always image-name
```

Where:

```
--detach , -d        Run container in background and print container ID
--name                Assign a name to the container
--publish , -p        Publish a container’s port(s) to the host
--volume , -v        Bind mount a volume
--restart            Restart policy to apply when a container exits
```

For more information, please check out the official [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. I ran my Docker image, and it created a container with a specific CONTAINER_ID. I wanted to work with the same container:

First run your Docker image:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v ~/:/host waleedka/modern-deep-learning
```

Then list all the containers you have made:

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

And select the container you want to work with (mine is 167ddd6d7f15):

```
sudo docker start -ai 167ddd6d7f15
```

Answer (score 8):

To view a list of all images on your Docker host, run:

```
  $ docker images
   REPOSITORY          TAG           IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
   apache_snapshot     latest        13037686eac3        22 seconds ago      249MB
   ubuntu              latest        00fd29ccc6f1        3 weeks ago         111MB
```

Now you can run the Docker image as a container in interactive mode:

```
   $ docker run -it apache_snapshot /bin/bash
```

OR if you don't have any images locally,Search Docker Hub for an image to download:

```
    $ docker search ubuntu
    NAME                            DESCRIPTION             STARS  OFFICIAL  AUTOMATED
    ubuntu                          Ubuntu is a Debian...   6759   [OK]       
    dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc  Ubuntu with openss...   141              [OK]
    rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd          Dockerized SSH ser...   114              [OK]
    ansible/ubuntu14.04-ansible     Ubuntu 14.04 LTS w...   88               [OK]
    ubuntu-upstart                  Upstart is an even...   80     [OK]
```

Pull the Docker image from a repository with the docker pull command:

```
     $ docker pull ubuntu
```

Run the Docker image as a container:

```
     $ docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example to run a webdev service in Docker.
The image's name is **morrisjobke/webdav**. You can pull it from [Docker Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Components).

After you run these images, you can then access the [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) instance at `http://localhost:8888/webdav`. Internally the folder `/var/webdav` is used as the WebDAV root.

You can run this container in the following way:

```
$ docker run -d -e USERNAME=test -e PASSWORD=test -p 8888:80 morrisjobke/webdav
```

Comment: Re *"run a webdev service"*: Do you mean *"run a  WebDAV service"*? Or *"run a  web development service"*?

Answer (score 6):

Since you have created an image from the Dockerfile, the image currently is not in active state. In order to work you need to run this image inside a container.

The `$ docker images` command describes how many images are currently available in the local repository.
and

```
docker ps -a
```

shows how many containers are currently available, i.e. the list of active and exited containers.

There are two ways to run the image in the container:

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

In detached mode:

```
-d=false: Detached mode: Run container in the background, print new container id
```

In interactive mode:

```
-i :Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

Here is the Docker run command

```
$ docker run image_name:tag_name
```

For more clarification on Docker run, you can visit *[Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)*.

It's the best material to understand Docker.

Answer (score 3):

**Follow only 5 steps to run docker image as a container**

1. > docker build -t dockerImageName .
2. > docker run -t -d -p 3030:3000 --name containerName dockerImageName

You can specified your own new containerName

3. Check container is running type:

> docker ps -all
> 4. Finally open your google chrome and type **localhost:3030**

You have successfully run docker image as a container
**Congrats**

5. If docker container is in exited state then Type below command to Run

> docker start ContainerId

Answer (score 0):

For those who had the same problem as well, but encountered an error like

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

I added an entry point that was worked for me:

`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh` for the images without Bash.

Example (from the approved example):

```
run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh ubuntu:12.04
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/mitchwongho/11266726

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED            
jamesmedice/marketplace   latest              e78c49b5f380        2 days ago          
jamesmedice/marketplace   v1.0.0              *e78c49b5f380*        2 days ago          


$ docker run -p 6001:8585 *e78c49b5f380*
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.