# How do I run an image in a container?

Tags: docker

I am following the instructions on [Migrating ASP.NET MVC Applications to Windows Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc)

I used

```
docker pull microsoft/aspnet
```

and it seemed to download correctly.

I am trying to follow the instruction "When you run this image in your container"

when I type

```
 docker run 5e
```

I get the following screen which seems to have locked up.
[image]

Am I typing the right thing?

When I run

```
docker images
```

I see that the microsoft/aspnet has tag "latest"

Another image also has the tag "latest"

If I type

```
docker run -it --name myapp 5e
```

then I see the same thing as previously but ending with the line "Service 'w3svc' was started

[image]

Thus it seems the -it command is helpful to making me feel like I have started the container successfully.

I can't actually get help on what "-it" does because it is not listed when I run

docker run --help

Though I understand it to mean "interactive terminal"

The phrase "run an image in a container" has me confused.
Would it be more appropriate to say "Create a container from an image and run it" ?

Comment: Please refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497688/run-a-docker-image-as-a-container This may helps you.

Comment: Could you paste some lines from the picture to the post? It make it easier to find it using a search engine.

Comment: Studying https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form

Comment: `docker run -it` is shorthand for `docker run -i -t` combining two different options: "Keep STDIN open even if not attached" and "Allocate a pseudo-tty". This is necessary if you're going to connect to a command line running in the container. An image is used to create a container. It's a template basically. Also you don't run an image in a container, that sentence is perhaps better written "When you us this image in your container". None of this explains why the image is repeating that message, but you're doing nothing wrong.

Comment: @ManoMarks In the course I did I.T stood for interactive Terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Docker [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) states

"The docker run command must specify an IMAGE to derive the container from"

I guess the usage of the word "derive" does imply that run creates the container if it is not there.

I think the reason the container appears locked up in my example is that the service I am starting is not a process that requires user input.