# How can i move .war to value-folder of host machine from docker-composer?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I have a composer file:

```
version: '2'
services:
        applic:
              image: tomcat
              ports:
                    - "8082:8080"
              depends_on:
                    - rabbit_image
                    -packager
              volumes:
                    - "/home/ustin/second_try/common_data:/home"
       rabbit_image:
              image: rabbitmq
              ports:
                    - "15673:5672"
       packager:
              build:
                     context: ./maven_images
                     dockerfile: Dockerfile
              volumes:
                    - "/home/ustin/second_try/common_data:/home"
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven
RUN mkdir clonefolder && cd clonefolder && git clone <repo.git> && cd docker-test-task && mvn clean package && cd target/ && cp docker-test-task-1.0.war /home && cd /home && ls
```

The main idea: using Dockerfile in image with maven i want to clone repo, create .war file using "clean package" command and lay it to "/home" folder, that before was defined as volume-folder and linked with "/home/ustin/second_try/common_data" on host-machine. At this moment i expect .war file on my host-machine. And then i want to get this .war to other image and lay this file into tomcat.

Question is: why i cannot find .war file not in my image in /home folder (but cp command was succesful), not in host-machine folder ? (ubuntu)

All steps - done:
with re-build: http://prntscr.com/jrolk7
or cached: http://prntscr.com/jrolun

Answer (score 1):

You are running all of your commands in one `RUN` directive. You are  building an image with one layer in which your compiled .war file exists.

The short answer is that you need to run a container using this image and `docker cp` your file out of it onto your host.

The long answer is that you should consider creating a reusable image that will dynamically build your WAR file and output to your host using a volume.

Here is some info on best practices for Dockerfiles: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: ok, but i don't understand where i should run "docker cp" command.. in "command" block of current service in composer file ?(

Comment: First you need to start up a container using the image. See documentation here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497688/run-a-docker-image-as-a-container

After you start the container, you can run `docker cp` against the container. See more here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Note that this is not the long-term, recommended solution to this problem - the "long answer" option above is far more preferable and maintainable.