# Docker seems unable to find locally stored image

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a container from the `node:lts` image, which I have in my cache. This is the output from `docker images` -

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
girimh/p1             latest              17b91de3ed61        4 weeks ago         6.89MB
manishgiri/cloud-p1   latest              a0f6b6aa8f00        4 weeks ago         6.89MB
mongo                 3.6                 a99bf141ff5b        2 months ago        435MB
ubuntu                latest              2ca708c1c9cc        2 months ago        64.2MB
node                  lts                 636ef87129d6        2 months ago        904MB
hello-world           latest              fce289e99eb9        11 months ago       1.84kB
mailhog/mailhog       latest              e00a21e210f9        13 months ago       19.2MB
```

However, when I try to run a container from this image, Docker is unable to find the image locally. I've tried running with both the name (`node:lts`) as well as the image ID.

```
$ docker run -it 636ef87129d6 /bin/bash                                                                                                                               
Unable to find image '636ef87129d6:latest' locally

$ docker run -it node:lts /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'node:lts' locally
```

I made sure the syntax is correct by verifying it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498313/2981518), but it seems fine.

Screenshot -

[image]

Comment: definitly your syntax is right.

Comment: Have you tried with a regular windows shell? Any particular reason for using git-bash?

Comment: Since I have the older Docker Toolbox installed (Windows 10 Home doesn't support docker desktop), I have to run the "Docker Quick Start Terminal" for it to power up a VM and allocate the IPs. This quickstart terminal happens to use git bash, no other reason.