# Failed to find attribute 'app' in Docker when image is run

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

I am having a challenge solving an error in Docker. I am building a Flask app and want to deploy it on Docker containers, but when I run my successfully created image using `docker run`, I get the error `Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'gossip_app'`.

Here is the full error message from `docker logs`:

```py
[2020-10-30 09:54:41,411] INFO in __init__: Tinker ChatApp
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> a6664359912e, Add user table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade a6664359912e -> 6b7e8489b0ee, Add post table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 6b7e8489b0ee -> a8b409f2c772, Add fields to user table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade a8b409f2c772 -> 2a3289732dbc, add followed field in user table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2a3289732dbc -> d055880868f7, Add language field to post table
[2020-10-30 09:54:42,426] INFO in __init__: Tinker ChatApp
compiling catalog app/translations/sw/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po to app/translations/sw/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
compiling catalog app/translations/zh/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po to app/translations/zh/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
[2020-10-30 09:54:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-10-30 09:54:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
[2020-10-30 09:54:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-10-30 09:54:42 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'gossip_app'.
[2020-10-30 09:54:42 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
[2020-10-30 09:54:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-10-30 09:54:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

My Flask app is structured as:

```
1_work_gossip_chat_app
               |------------app/
               |------------boot.sh
               |------------Dockerfile
               |------------config.py
               |------------tinker.py
               |------------requirements.txt
```

I created my image by updating the `Dockerfile` and the `boot.sh` file which acts as an executable, as seen below:

`Dockerfile`

```py
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN adduser -D gossip_app

WORKDIR /home/software_development/python/current_projects/1_work_gossip_chat_app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv gossip_app
RUN gossip_app/bin/python3 -m pip  install --upgrade pip

RUN \
# install psycopg2 dependancies
 apk update && \
 apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev && \
 # then install your requirements
 gossip_app/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
 gossip_app/bin/pip3 install gunicorn pymysql

COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY tinker.py config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP tinker.py

RUN chown -R gossip_app:gossip_app ./
USER gossip_app

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "./boot.sh" ]
```

`boot.sh`

```py
#!/bin/sh
source gossip_app/bin/activate
flask db upgrade
flask translate compile 
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - gossip_app:app
```

I understand that from the error `gunicorn` is telling me that there is no Flask app instance in `gossip_app`. `gossip_app` to the best of my knowledge is the new user and also the new owner of the files and directories.

What could I be getting wrong when creating this container?

I have looked at several examples of how to build and run an image in Docker such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497688/run-a-docker-image-as-a-container) and everything works very well, except for the one error I am admittedly struggling to debug for days on end.

Comment: How are you starting the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I run this: `docker build -t gossip_app:latest .` to create a container image. `docker run --name gossip_app -d -p 8000:5000 gossip_app -rm gossip_app:latest` to create a container from the image. I include the option `-rm` to ensure that the container is deleted once it is terminated.  `docker ps -a` is the command that shows this container is not running while it should be running after a successful `run`.