dockerfile, port not responding even though mentioned using -p tag
I tried creating dockerfile for my flask-app but it doesn't work on localhost.
->dockerfile:
FROM python:3-alpine3.15
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run"]

->from terminal:
docker build -t hello-world:0.0.1 .
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 hello-world:0.0.1
after using these command docker image is created and also it run properly
Image of working ports
I tried using different approaches python image like 3.10-sim, 3.10-buster but it doesn't work with it,

look into it and try will helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497688/run-a-docker-image-as-a-container . I think your port matching is wrong

Flask's dev server by default listens on the container-private localhost address, and it's unreachable outside of Docker.  You need flask run --host 0.0.0.0 if you're launching it this way, as per this answer.
